# How does getaddrinfo work with a dualstack source?

Tags: dns, rfc, round-robin, getaddrinfo

Some background:

We are running go based applications on ubuntu servers on AWS. Recently we started having DNS round-robin issues where one of the load balancers (ELB) will end up handling a large portion of the traffic(~ 5:1) and thus overloading the load balancer.

After some investigation, we came across [rfc3484](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) and [issues](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=438179) associated with it that explained the behaviour that we were experiencing. Seeing how the rfc is mostly catered towards ipv6, we then decided to try disabling ipv6 and see what happens. Somehow, that magically solved our problems.

Can someone explain to me why would disabling ipv6 at the source also disable the sorting that is done in `getaddrinfo`?

Note: The ELBs that we are using do not support ipv6. Only the source is configured to have ipv4 and ipv6 by default.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `getaddrinfo`? By default Go uses its own DNS, see https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution

Comment: @PerJohansson Yeah. There was no apparent way to get Go to work and so we decided to use cgo to do dns resolution until we can figure it out. Enabling/disabling ipv6 doesn't do anything for the pure go resolver.